# Error on package manager

Tags: command-line

I have an error every time I want to install something by the terminal and when I try on GNOME software center it just doesn't install it :

[image: Imagic problem]

Before that I execute some codes on the terminal like this , I don't now if has to do something with this :

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Comment: Try `apt-get update` and then retry.

Comment: Consider copy-and-pasting the terminal text into your question instead of making people download a screenshot.

Comment: ok I ll "consider" it the next time